# HSQLDB Order By with multiple columns

Tags: sql, hibernate, hsqldb

I am performing a query using hsqldb and hibernate.  I have an order by statement: -

```
Query query = em
    .createQuery("SELECT DISTINCT new com.mytransferobject.QuickSearchResultTO(m.id, m.firstName||' '||m.surname, '')  " +
        "FROM Member m, ClassC c, ClassCm cm " +
        "WHERE  c.id = cm.clubId AND m.id = cm.memberId " +
        "AND c.lft >= :lft AND c.lft <= :rgt " +
        "AND (firstName LIKE :memberName OR surname LIKE :memberName) " +
        "AND m.deleted = false " +
        "AND c.deleted = false " +
        "ORDER BY m.firstName, m.surname");

query.setParameter("lft", lft);
query.setParameter("rgt", rgt);
query.setParameter("memberName", memberName + "%");
```

This works fine in MYSQL, but fails in my test code (using hsqldb 2.2.6).  I tried concatenating them together and it works ok, but this is a highly used query, so I'd like to avoid any unnecessary operations.

I am getting an exception: -

```
    javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: invalid ORDER BY expression
        at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1360)
        at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1288)
        at org.hibernate.ejb.QueryImpl.getResultList(QueryImpl.java:261)
        at com.servasport.smp.dao.jpa.MemberDaoImpl.quickSearchAll(MemberDaoImpl.java:626)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:318)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:110)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)
        at $Proxy68.quickSearchAll(Unknown Source)
        at com.servasport.smp.dao.MemberDaoTest.quickSearchSuccess(MemberDaoTest.java:768)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
        at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
        at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:41)
        at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:20)
        at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:28)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:74)
        at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:31)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:83)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:72)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:231)
        at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:49)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:193)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:52)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:191)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:42)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:184)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:71)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:236)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:174)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
    Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: invalid ORDER BY expression
        at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.convert(SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.java:83)
        at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:49)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:125)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:110)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.proxy.ConnectionProxyHandler.continueInvocation(ConnectionProxyHandler.java:146)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.proxy.AbstractProxyHandler.invoke(AbstractProxyHandler.java:81)
        at $Proxy95.prepareStatement(Unknown Source)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$5.doPrepare(StatementPreparerImpl.java:147)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$StatementPreparationTemplate.prepareStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:166)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl.prepareQueryStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:145)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.prepareQueryStatement(Loader.java:1720)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:828)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:289)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2447)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2433)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2263)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2258)
        at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:470)
        at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:355)
        at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:196)
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1161)
        at org.hibernate.internal.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:101)
        at org.hibernate.ejb.QueryImpl.getResultList(QueryImpl.java:252)
        ... 43 more
    Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: invalid ORDER BY expression
        at org.hsqldb.jdbc.Util.sqlException(Unknown Source)
        at org.hsqldb.jdbc.Util.sqlException(Unknown Source)
        at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCPreparedStatement.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCConnection.prepareStatement(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.proxy.ConnectionProxyHandler.continueInvocation(ConnectionProxyHandler.java:138)
        ... 61 more
    Caused by: org.hsqldb.HsqlException: invalid ORDER BY expression
        at org.hsqldb.error.Error.error(Unknown Source)
        at org.hsqldb.error.Error.error(Unknown Source)
        at org.hsqldb.QuerySpecification.resolveGroups(Unknown Source)
        at org.hsqldb.QuerySpecification.resolveTypesPartTwo(Unknown Source)
        at org.hsqldb.QueryExpression.resolve(Unknown Source)
        at org.hsqldb.ParserDQL.compileCursorSpecification(Unknown Source)
        at org.hsqldb.ParserCommand.compilePart(Unknown Source)
        at org.hsqldb.ParserCommand.compileStatement(Unknown Source)
        at org.hsqldb.Session.compileStatement(Unknown Source)
        at org.hsqldb.StatementManager.compile(Unknown Source)
        at org.hsqldb.Session.execute(Unknown Source)
        ... 68 more
```

Comment: How does it fail? Any exception stack trace? What do you want it to do, and what does it do instead?

Comment: You are performing which query? What is the failure? `ORDER BY firstname, surname` is supported by HSQLDB.

Comment: Sorry was in a meeting, I have added the exception now.  I tried updating to 2.2.8 (the latest on maven), but the same exception

Comment: Your ORDER BY syntax is correct in the segment you've shown. Possibly wrong is the position of the clause (say you have ORDER BY before WHERE or something similar) but we can't tell you exactly what's wrong if you don't post the full code.

Comment: Added the full code (removing some table names to protect the innocent).  I suspect the problem is that I don't actually select firstName and surname individually?

Comment: @Ash, yes, this is probably the reason, because you have used DISTINCT.

Answer (score 9):

Probably, you have the exception "invalid order by expression" because you specify a column in `ORDER BY` (in your case, `m.firstName` and `m.surname`) that are not explicit returned in the `SELECT` clause. Some databases, like SQL Server and MySQL don't need this, but others like HSQLDB and DB2 cannot do this ORDER BY without the fields in SELECT too.

I think your code will work if you use:

```
Query query = em
    .createQuery("SELECT DISTINCT new com.mytransferobject.QuickSearchResultTO(m.id, m.firstName, m.surname, m.firstName||' '||m.surname, '')  " +
        "FROM Member m, ClassC c, ClassCm cm " +
        "WHERE  c.id = cm.clubId AND m.id = cm.memberId " +
        "AND c.lft >= :lft AND c.lft <= :rgt " +
        "AND (firstName LIKE :memberName OR surname LIKE :memberName) " +
        "AND m.deleted = false " +
        "AND c.deleted = false " +
        "ORDER BY m.firstName, m.surname");
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, I fixed it by using GROUP BY instead of DISTINCT, it return the same result.
Your code will work if you use:

```
Query query = em
.createQuery("SELECT new com.mytransferobject.QuickSearchResultTO(m.id, m.firstName||' '||m.surname, '')  " +
    "FROM Member m, ClassC c, ClassCm cm " +
    "WHERE  c.id = cm.clubId AND m.id = cm.memberId " +
    "AND c.lft >= :lft AND c.lft <= :rgt " +
    "AND (firstName LIKE :memberName OR surname LIKE :memberName) " +
    "AND m.deleted = false " +
    "AND c.deleted = false " +
    "GROUP BY m.idORDER BY m.firstName, m.surname");
```